# Android setContentView(View) throws NullPointerException related to appcompat-7 library

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, android-appcompat, appcompatactivity

I've been developing Android apps for a long time and I've faced with many problems which were resolved at the end of day, but in my last project I have a really weird problem which is related to appcompat-7 library I suspect.

A `NullPointerException` is thrown approximately with 10% frequency when `setContentView(View)` is called. I mean the exception is not thrown in each execution. There is an indeterministic behaviour.

Being not sure, I think I miss a key point about `DecorView` of `Window`.

The exception is thrown at line `cfl.setDecorPadding(windowDecor.getPaddingLeft()...` in method `applyFixedSizeWindow` of class `AppCompatDelegateImplV9`.

I also attached the exception's full stack trace at the end of the question.

I don't think it is relevant but it is useful to say that I use Android Studio 3.0.

All suggestions and comments are welcome.

Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...

private static final int HIDE_NAVBAR_DELAY = 500;

private static void hideNavBarAndActionBar(final Window _window) {
    _window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.screen_splash, null, false);
    setContentView(view);

    final Window window = getWindow();

    // to hide bars after volume control popup or similar popup appears and disappers
    window.getDecorView().setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                hideNavBarAndActionBar(window);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    //to hide of bars after activity window is focused (example case: resume activity by bringing ti from background to foreground)
    if(hasFocus) {
        final Window window = getWindow();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                hideNavBarAndActionBar(window);
            }
        }, HIDE_NAVBAR_DELAY);
    }
}
...
```

}

build.gradle for the module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
}
```

Stack trace of the exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: my_package_name:my_process_name, PID: 25792
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my_package_name/my_package_name.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.applyFixedSizeWindow(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:537)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:331)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:275)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:144)
      at my_package_name.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can't you just `setContentView(R.layout.screen_splash);` ? Also, try changing the version of `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`

Comment: I need an instance of that View. So, setting content with a resource id is not an option.  Changing the library version may solve the issue, but first I need to reveal the root cause. There is something that I miss.

Comment: I've found this exception happening to some of our users in Crashlytics, as well. Did you ever get to the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

I have test your code in my android studio 3 it's work fine this my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.asb.test.testapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: As I said in the question post, it does not always cause an exception. There is an indeterministic situation at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

try current appcompat library "`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'`" and `compileSdkVersion 27`, `targetSdkVersion 27` and rebuild project . Hope it would help you!

Comment: When I upgrade the library version, I get the following warning which introduces an additional complexity to the environment. Do you get this warning? Please share your build.gradle.

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.0.0, 25.2.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0
There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs...

Comment: yeep i am using all 27.0.0  and don't have warnings.  dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.4.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}